# Mask package version in Yum on CentOS

Tags: centos, yum, downgrade

I can't seem to find anything useful in the man pages etc for this, but it seems like it should be straightforward..?

Our servers are running CentOS 6.8 but also have the Atomic repository for some package versions. The most recent version of one of the packages that Atomic provides seems to be broken, so we've had to do a yum downgrade of that package.

Problem now is that we're running Plesk, which performs automatic Yum updates on a schedule, and the next time this happens, the broken package will just drag back in again!

All I want to do is tell Yum to ignore this specific package version so that it updates the next time there's a newer version, but skips the current.

I found that I can add exclude= lines to yum.conf but I can't seem to find how to define a specific version number in this exclude. It looks like I can only exclude entire package names?

I'm more familiar with Gentoo where we can tell Portage to mask specific versions when problems like this occur. Is this not an option in CentOS?

Much appreciated.

Comment: I know which your broken packages is. You can fix the update installation and may not worry about that one update any more. See Plesk Support ticket https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001906725 .

Just run command `install -m 0700 -o mysql -g mysql -d /var/lib/mysql-files` to make sure the broken "mysql" works fine again.

Comment: Thanks Matthias. You're absolutely right, it is indeed the MySQL packages that I'm referring to. We've already performed a yum downgrade of mysql-libs, mysql and mysql-server to resolve so our servers are operating fine, but I assumed we'd need to block the broken packages to prevent another occurrence... It now sounds like I just need to create that missing folder and chmod it?

Comment: Answered my own question - creating /var/lib/mysql-files and using chmod + chown to set the proper ownership and permissions as per Matthias' line above, before letting yum then bring the broken packages in, seems to have worked. I'll leave this thread open though as I'd still like to know how to mask broken packages ideally...